# Пустые конструктор и деструктор

Tags: c++, qt, qtcreator, деструктор

Есть два вопроса  по одному проекту.

Пишу шахматы на С++ и использую Qt. Для каждый фигуры сделал свой класс и унаследовал это все от своего класса figure. Переменные класса figure не создаю, создаю переменные наследованных классов (pawn, king и прочее) и добавляю их в вектор vector.

1. Преподаватель в вузе увидел код, в котором в классе figure объявлены пустые конструктор и деструктор и попросил ответить на вопрос, почему так делать нельзя, самостоятельно не нашел ответа и взываю к вашей помощи.
2. Когда к вектору vector white пытаюсь применить:

   white.erase(white.begin() + 1)

выдает 2 ошибки:

1. use of deleted function 'figure& figure::operator=(const figure&)'
2. use of deleted function 'QObject& QObject::operator=(const QObject&)'

Вот файл Figure.h

```
#ifndef FIGURE_H
#define FIGURE_H
#include <QObject>
#include <QVector>

using namespace std;

class figure : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    figure();
    int x;
    int y;
    bool alive;
    bool active;
    bool castling = true;
    figure (const figure &other);
    figure& operator=(const figure &other);
    ~figure();
```

Figure.cpp

```
#include "figure.h"


figure::figure()
{
    
}

figure::figure(const figure &other)
{
    this->x = other.x;
    this->y = other.y;
    this->alive = other.alive;
    this->active = other.active;
    this->castling = other.castling;
}

figure operator = (const figure &other)
{
    if (this != &other)
    {
      this->x = other.x;
      this->y = other.y;
      this->alive = other.alive;
      this->active = other.active;
      this->castling = other.castling;
    }
    return *this;
}

figure::~figure()
{
}
```

Comment: Возможно, он хотел увидеть их виртуальными?

Comment: особенно конструктор:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Скорее всего, преподавателю не понравилось то, что Вы нарушили [правило 3/5](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three)

Кратко в Вашем случае оно звучит так - если написал конструктор копирования, то и парный оператор присваивания должен быть написан. Собственно компилятор на это и ругается.

По поводу пустого конструктора - а зачем его писать, если Вам подходит конструктор по умолчанию? То же самое и с деструктором.

Но лучше применить правило нуля - Ваш конструктор тривиален и очевиден. Компилятор может и сам его сгенерировать. Так что можно убрать и в этом случае компилятор сгенерирует и оператор присваивания. И все будет работать.

Оператор перемещения должен выглядеть где то так

в объявлении класса

```
figure& operator=(figure other)
```

в с++ файле

```
figure& figure::operator=(figure other)
{
    std::swap(x, other.x);
    std::swap(y, other.y);
    // тут другие переменны
    return *this;
}
```

или так (тут аналогично как примере выше. или прям в хедере в объявлении класса вставляйте)

```
figure& operator=(const figure& other)
{
    if (this != &other) {
      this->x = other.x;
      this->y = other.y;
      this->alive = other.alive;
      this->active = other.active;
      this->castling = other.castling;
    }
    return *this;
}
```

или можно пойти дальше, и написать вот так

```
figure (const figure &other) = default;
figure& operator=(const figure& other) = default;
```

Comment: Вадим, здравствуйте.
Не могу удалить конструктор копирования, который описан в моем вопросе, потому что тогда при инициализации вектора и сразу же его заполнения получаю ошибку: call to implicitly-deleted copy constructor of 'const figure'
figure.h:8:16: note: copy constructor of 'figure' is implicitly deleted because base class 'QObject' has a deleted copy constructor

Comment: Поэтому вынужден оставить конструктор копирования, тогда если удаляю только конструктор и деструктор, то в наследуемых классах в файлах получаю ошибку constructor for 'king' must explicitly initialize the base class 'figure' which does not have a default constructor

Comment: тогда дописывайте оператор присваивания.

Comment: Спасибо большое за подробный код. Но он, к сожалению, не решает проблему, т.к. если пишу второй вариант вашего оператора в файл figure.cpp и figure& operator=(const figure& other) в файл figure.h, то получаю ошибку overloaded 'operator=' must be a binary operator (has 1 parameter)

Comment: тогда показывайте текущий код, иначе это будет угадывание

Comment: Изменил вопрос, отредактировал имеющийся код.
Ошибка: overloaded 'operator=' must be a binary operator (has 1 parameter)
И напротив каждого this ошибка invalid use of 'this' outside of a non-static member function

Comment: ой, ну это же функция-член.

Comment: Большое спасибо, проблема решена

Comment: не будет компилироваться. забыли амперсанты `figure& operator=(figure && other)`

Comment: Я посмотрел, Я вроде ничего не забыл. Но два амперсанда там точно не нужно ( или мы уже move семантику подключаем?)

Comment: не заметил **или**. Всё равно, одновременно не получится написать копирование и перемещение так : `C(C)`,`C(C const&)`

Comment: Пожалуйста, напишите Ваш вариант ответа, где изложите свои мысли.